# Naming buttons components AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-component

How to name through AS3 buttons components?

I have 3 buttons components: a BackButton, a ForwardButton and a PlayButton.

I have named them through the properties panel, (where it says 'Instance Name').

But once I click on them and check for event.target.name I receive, always 'button_mc'.

How could I name the buttons?

Answer (score 5):

If you set the property id from the properties panel, you should see it via the name property:

[image: Property Id]

Here the switch block shows which button was clicked.

[image: Button Switch]

For 3 buttons named: `backButton`, `playButton`, and `forwardButton` the following code will determine which was clicked.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

backButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
forwardButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(event.target.name)
    {
        case "backButton":
            trace("back button clicked");
            break;
        case "playButton":
            trace("play button clicked");
            break;
        case "forwardButton":
            trace("forward button clicked");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are using the Component 'Button', I´m using 3 different ones. 'BackButton', 'ForwardButton' and 'PlayButton'

Comment: @ Marcelo Noronha"Jason Sturges" select this guys answer, he went all out to answer it with images and everything.

Comment: @MarceloNoronha - do you mean the FLV Playback Components?  The event bubbles up, so maybe rely on event listens to differentiate the selected button.